# Getting TokenMismatchException when using nested AJAX calls. Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, csrf

I get `TokenMismatchException` when using nested AJAX calls. The first AJAX call works fine but the second always goes to error instead of success.

What I'm trying to do is that when the user registers from the button in the nav bar I want him to go to the dashboard or `/home` - this works okay. But, when the user fills the form (to buy something) on the index page, I want him to:

Have his input checked for validity, then, check if he's logged in, if not then the registration modal pops up. After he's registered I want him to be redirected to the checkout page.

However, what happens is that when the user fills the buying form and hits submit, the first ajax checks if the input in the buying form is valid, if it is, then check if he's logged in if not return 401 error.

401 gets picked up by the first ajax and directs the flow to 401 handling where the registration modal pops up to register, that's when the 2nd ajax pop up. After he's registered the back-end keeps returning 500 because of CSRF token mismatch.

First, this is the nested ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#topup-form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var topup_info = $('form').serialize();

            //FIRST AJAX
            $.ajax({
                url: $('form').attr('action'),
                method: 'post',
                data: topup_info,
                type: 'json',


                //if success show success message for user
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result.responseJSON.code);
                    $('.alert.error').slideUp(200);
                    $('.alert.success').append("<p class='lead'>Thanks! To checkout we go!</p>").slideDown(200);
                },


                //for error check if it's 400 (validation) or 401(authentication)
                error: function(errorData){
                    // alert(errorData.responseJSON.code);
                    if(errorData.responseJSON.code === 400){
                        var error = errorData.responseJSON.message;
                        $('.alert.error').text('');
                        $('.alert.success').slideUp(200);


                        for (var i in error){
                            for (var j in error[i]) {
                                var message = error[i][j];
                                $('.alert.error').append("<p class='lead'>" + message + "<p>");
                            }
                        }

                        $('.alert.error').slideDown(00);
                    }//end error 400



                    //for authentication failure, show registeration modal
                    else if (errorData.responseJSON.code === 401) {

                        //change somethings in registeration modal
                        $('#myModalLabel').html('Please Login First');
                        $('#register').trigger('click');
                        document.getElementById('formRegister').action = "{{ route('user.regtopup') }}";


                        //when registeration form is submitted..
                        $('#formRegister').submit(function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();

                            //fire 2nd ajax
                            $.ajax({
                                url: $('#formRegister').attr('action'),
                                method: 'post',
                                data: $('form').serialize(),
                                type: 'json',

                                success: function(result){
                                    alert('success!!!');
                                },


                                //it keeps going to error! complaining about csrf token mismatch
                                error: function(result){
                                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                                },
                            })//end of 2nd ajax
                        });//end of 2nd submit
                    }//end of 401
                }//end of error
            });//end of first ajax
        });//end of first submit

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Second, this is the controller that checks input validity and return 401 when not registered:

```
public function etiPost(Request $request) {
        $validator = [
        'topupAmount'=> 'required|integer|between:10,500',
        'phonenumber'=> 'required|regex:/^05[602][0-9]{7}$/',
        ];

        $inputs = $request->all();

        Log::info($inputs);

        $validator = Validator::make($inputs, $validator);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return Response::json([
                'error' => true,
                'message' => $validator->messages(),
                'code' => 400
            ], 400);
        }

        elseif (Auth::check()) {
             return view('pages.checkout', compact('inputs')); 
         }

         else {

              return Response::json([
                'error' => true,
                'message' => "Please login first",
                'code' => 401
            ], 401); 
        }   
    }
```

This is the overloaded `register` method that returns JSON when registration is successful. Here is where 500 is returned! When I Log the returned JSON it comes out as normal 200 response but it arrives at the "Whoops" 500 error to the 2nd ajax! The user is registered successfully in the database but this method returns 500 which is caught by the `error` part of the ajax call.

```
    /**
 * Handle a registration request for the application (overloaded).
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    $this->guard()->login($this->create($request->all()));

    // return response()->json();
    return response()->json(['msg' => 'Success! You have been registered!'], 200);
}
```

I won't include the forms for brevity but rest assured I added all the CSRF input tags and the meta tag in the `head` of the HTML.

What should I do differently to avoid this? The first ajax works but the second doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Set header token for each  ajax call

```
headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
```

Also note that you have to add mete token in your template

you can add meta token like this in template

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

if you still want to disable csrf token then

**Excluding URIs From CSRF Protection**

Sometimes you may wish to exclude a set of URIs from CSRF protection. For example, if you are using Stripe to process payments and are utilizing their webhook system, you will need to exclude your Stripe webhook handler route from CSRF protection since Stripe will not know what CSRF token to send to your routes.

Typically, you should place these kinds of routes outside of the web middleware group that the  RouteServiceProvider applies to all routes in the routes/web.php file. However, you may also exclude the routes by adding their URIs to the $except property of the VerifyCsrfToken middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
    ];
}
```

Instead of `'stripe/*',` if you give `'/*'` then it will disable token for all
For more detail :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: thanks but I already added the $.ajaxSetup and when I exclude URIs I receive this error: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"email\":[\"The email has already been taken.\"],\"password\":[\"The password confirmation does not match.\"]}","responseJSON":{"email":["The email has already been taken."],"password":["The password confirmation does not match."]},"status":422,"statusText":"Unprocessable Entity"}

Comment: now this is validation erorr.all validation erorr in laravel throw 422 error.if its useful .please mark answr as accepted

Answer (score 0):

please follow code in your jquery before ajax call

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

it's not advisable to add CSRF token in meta because all pages are not contain form to submit value so use this solution so you can use CSRF only for your js perspective.

Thank you